# Using Elasticsearch with RSpec and Factorygirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, rspec, factory-bot

I found a great article on integrating Elasticsearch with RSpec [here](http://benjaminknofe.com/blog/2014/06/14/rspec-testing-rails-with-elasticsearch/), but whenever I create a model with Factorygirl it doesn't seem to be getting added to my Elasticsearch index. Any ideas on how to add models to Elasticsearch using Factorygirl?

Here's my code

display_controller_spec.rb:

```
    it "will return a list of displays", :elasticsearch do
      FactoryGirl.create(:display, client: @client)

      get :index, { :format => :json }, { "Accept" => "application/json" }
      # returns Status: 200 OK
      expect(response.status).to eq 200

      json = JSON.parse(response.body)
      expect(json.count).to be > 0
    end
```

display.rb:

```
    require 'elasticsearch/model'

    class Display < ActiveRecord::Base
      include Elasticsearch::Model
      include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
      index_name ['company', Rails.env, self.base_class.to_s.pluralize.underscore].join('_')
...
```

factories/displays.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:display_name) {|n| "Display ##{n}"}

  factory :display do
    name { generate(:display_name) }
    client
  end
end
```

spec_helper.rb:

```
  config.before(:each) do
    [Event, Interaction, Perch].each do |model|
      model.__elasticsearch__.create_index!(force: true)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Did you setup the ES indexes in your `spec_helper.rb`?

Comment: I believe I did. I've added it to the post above, let me know if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I have this setup working.  I think you are just missing a call to Model.import to import the records into elasticsearch.  You also need to make sure any factory creates happen in a let! block, not within your test so that the import will pick up those new records.  Try something like this:

display_controller_spec.rb:

```
context "elasticsearch tests" do
  let!(:display) { FactoryGirl.create(:display, client: @client) }

  it "will return a list of displays", :elasticsearch do
    get :index, { :format => :json }, { "Accept" => "application/json" }
    # returns Status: 200 OK
    expect(response.status).to eq 200

    json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    expect(json.count).to be > 0
  end
end
```

spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  ...

  ES_CLASSES = [Event, Interaction, Perch]

  config.before :all do
    ES_CLASSES.each do |esc|
      esc.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.create(
        index: esc.index_name,
        body: { settings: esc.settings.to_hash, mappings: esc.mappings.to_hash }
      )
    end
  end

  config.after :all do
    ES_CLASSES.each do |esc|
      esc.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.delete index: esc.index_name
    end
  end

  config.before(:each, elasticsearch: true) do
    ES_CLASSES.each { |esc| esc.import(refresh: true, force: true) }
  end
end
```